# What is the interest to implement a statistics model in a groupby object instead of use the whole groups in a sample?

Tags: data-mining, machine-learning-model

I saw this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544805/python-pandas-how-to-run-multiple-univariate-regression-by-group) and also this [one](https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/02-groupby.html#Groupby-Apply) in dask documentation.

I wonder what is the real interest to make a model for each group instead of considering a whole sample where all groups would appear? As far as I know the more informations you have, sure the more complexity you have (not good for overfitting), the more the trained model is fitting the reality. So what is the goal?
More precisely, after you answer the generality above, is it interesting to make odds ratio with a logistic regression where each model is applied on one group (excluding others in each model)? What are the pros, cons, then the limits?